# Problema en la utilización de los Eventos de un Atributo insertado

Tags: genexus

Cuando tenemos dentro de un objeto Panel SD, objetos "Textblock" lo que noté es que
si en tiempo de ejecución le ingreso otro valor me obliga a moverme con el dedo
a otro objeto textblock para que se dispare el evento "ControlValueChanged".
Con lo cual si modifico la cantidad de días en el TXTB02 y no me muevo al TXTB01, no se recalculan las fechas.
Entonces, en qué Evento debería ubicar la lógica que tiene que re-dispararse al cambiar los valores?
Ya probé colocandolo en el Evento "ControlValueChanging" pero al modificar el valor ingresado TXTB02, se cierra la app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para que se dispare el controlValueChanged tenes que sacar el foco del campo modificado. Capaz para este caso es mejor que uses el control value changing como decis en tu mensaje, tendrias que ver por que razon se cae la aplicacion. Porba prender el debug a nivel de main y ver que error te da al caer, pero seguramente sea la mejor opcion.

Comment: Por desconocimiento, yo estaba omitiendo el parametro de entrada del evento ControlValueChanging. Lo agregué tal como idica este link 
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?35768,ControlValueChanging%20event
Y me funcionó ok. Ya no se cierra la app cuando la ejecución del programa pasa por el Evento Event ctlSDTvitaminadAppDiasPreavisoCompra.ControlValueChanging(&vDiasPreavisoChanging)